# SQL filter Date from Label in VB.net

Tags: sql, filter

I am stuck with little problem. I have a `sql` database with DATE column. It is populated from a Label like this: **Label1.text = Date.today**
and need to show records from one date in **datagridwiev**. So I need filter date using date from Label. So far I have this:

```
 Public Sub ShowData()
        cmd = New SqlCommand("Select * FROM Cisnik WHERE Datum = #" & Label3.Text & "# ", con)
        If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Open()
        myDA = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        myDataSet = New DataSet()
        myDA.Fill(myDataSet, "Cisnik")
        DGV3.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables("Cisnik").DefaultView
    End Sub
```

This code throws : `Incorrect syntax near '11.'. The number 11 is a part of European form of date 24.12.2018`
The database works OK. Only need this filter problem to solve.

Comment: Sorry about the code format :-(

Comment: Please specifically tag your RDBMS as *SQL database* is not clear enough. Many databases uses SQL as a language. Did you mean SQL Server, Postgres, Oracle, MySQL, even MS Access? This is particularly needed since your date literals depend on the database vendor.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 cmd = New SqlCommand("Select * FROM Cisnik WHERE Datum = '" &  cdate(label3.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "'", con)
```

Your query will be:

```
Select * FROM Cisnik WHERE Datum = '2018-11-11'
```

(date example)

Comment: This does not work as toShortDateTime() is not member of Date. The column in database is Date (not DateTime)

Comment: use this so:  cmd = New SqlCommand("Select * FROM Cisnik WHERE Datum = '" &  cdate(label3.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "'", con)

Comment: YES!! Thanks a lot! It works - the second line. It is SQL server

Comment: Yes I did. Thanks again